# Box2D debug draw with OpenGL ES 2

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I've created Cocos2D 2.1 project without Box2D initially and then later added Box2D. So far so good, the only problem for now is that my project looks like by default using OpenGL ES 2 and the one with Box2D is using OpenGL ES 1. This is debug draw method:

```
-(void) draw
{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    _world->DrawDebugData();

    // restore default GL states
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

`GL_COLOR_ARRAT` and `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` are not defined for OGL2 and I got compiler errors. What are my options here to have debug draw in my project?

Comment: create a new cocos+box2d project and copy gles-render files to your project

Comment: glres-render files contains `DrawDebugData` method. However, the problem is in the `draw` method, where I use mentioned GL states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [Cocos2D migration to 2.0 guide](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3amigrate_to_v2.0). Specifically paying attention to custom `draw()` functions.  Sounds like you should just need to modify the OpenGL calls you're making to the ones Cocos2D uses since it handles alot of the OpenGL calls internally with 2.x.  I ran into this issue as well recently.